# How to count the no. of HOLD entry between the Two ACTIVE entry

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to count the number of HOLD entry between the Two ACTIVE entries.

```
S.NO      DATA     STATUS
-----------------------------
   1       B       active
   2       D       hold
   3       C       active
   4       H       hold
   5       j       hold
   6       k       hold
   7       l       hold
   8       y       active
```

The output should be

```
COUNT OF HOLD
-------------
2
```

When HOLD entry comes between two ACTIVE entries we take it as a batch of HOLD entry.
Then we Count the whole Batch of HOLD entry in the table. In the above Example, there is one hold entry between two active, this is counted as 1.
Then another 4 HOLD entries between another two ACTIVE, This is counted to be 1.
So there are two counts. 1+1. So the output is 2.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Post some code, and what is your problem (in the code).

Comment: can the `status` be only HOLD and ACTIVE??

Comment: Put your query that u have tried here

Comment: sory i dnt try anything, only i think that i can use it thru CRUSOR or not, i want some help regarding this.

Comment: G one - yes we have only two things here Only HOLD & ACTIVE.

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of [LEAD](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions086.htm#SQLRF00656) function to look what is the status in the next row. Then count the occurrences where current row is active and next is hold.
Subtract 1 from it, and you have your output.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/90b5e/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
create table sam(
    sno_ number,
    data_ varchar2(5),
    status_ varchar2(10)
    );

insert into sam values(1,'a','hold');
insert into sam values(2,'b','active');
insert into sam values(3,'d','active');
insert into sam values(4,'s','hold');
insert into sam values(5,'c','active');
insert into sam values(6,'r','hold');
insert into sam values(7,'t','hold');
insert into sam values(8,'m','active');
insert into sam values(9,'y','hold');
```

**Query**:

```
select count(1) - 1 count_of_hold
from (
    select status_, lead(status_,1,'hold') over (order by sno_) next_status_
    from sam
    )
where status_ = 'active' and next_status_ = 'hold';
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/90b5e/1/1)**:

```
| COUNT_OF_HOLD |
|---------------|
|             2 |
```

Comment: +1 for Analytics tool. What if the last row ends as HOLD status rather than ACTIVE? Also vice versa (Starts with Hold rather than active??)You will ignore them?

Comment: Yes, this query ignores both those cases. @user3345235, What do you mean by "sql also"? This is sql. Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 4
'lead' is not a recognized built-in function name.

this error occurs while debuging the query

i make the whole table as u tell me..
and but the LEAD function is not recognized by them..
im using sqlserver 2012

Comment: You should have tagged the question appropriately. But still, LEAD is available in sql server 2012. You must be using earlier version. Check [this](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/11/24/sql-server-solution-to-puzzle-simulate-lead-and-lag-without-using-sql-server-2012-analytic-function/) for simulating LEAD function.